# Analyzing influence level

Tags: twitter, social-networking, ipython

I am using Ipython and through library Twython i am able to fetch tweets using user name.
Is it possible to analyze influence measure(like how influential is the person whose tweets i am retrieving) or what is the impact of tweets

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, yes, of course you can measure influence in some way from Twitter data.  On the other hand, you probably should give a decent amount of thought as to how you understand influence as a metric, how this relates to your data, and how you'll measure influence in your data.

A few things you might consider:

1.) In addition to pulling in tweets for individual users, you probably also want to pull in their profile information (e.g., follower count, total number of tweets, etc.).  By combining this data with the metadata from the Tweets, you'll have more to play with.

2.) Consider looking at some of the following data points, on a per individual basis:

- Share of tweets retweeted:  Say you pull in 1000 tweets for an individual; you can establish what percentage of these tweets are retweeted (e.g., what percentage of these tweets are influencing others to retweet).
- Average # of retweets per retweeted tweet: when the person is retweeted is it just one or two people that retweet him/her, or is it hudnreds?
- Follower counts:  This data point, on its own, tells you something. In general, it's probably the case that someone with more followers is more influential than someone with less.

3.) You also should think about topical relevance. If someone is getting retweeted a lot on Twitter and has a large followership, is it because of tweets related to their profession, or because they write about cats?  Depending on your use case and business logic, these sorts of questions can be critical.

These are just some starting points. I'd spend some time looking at the Twitter REST API 1.1 documentation and the Twython documentation so you get a better sense of which data points are available, and then think about how these data points might contribute to your measure of influence.

Good luck.

**EDIT**
If I understand correctly, vishal1985, in your comment you're asking how to use Twython to collect information about retweets.  This could mean one of several things, but I think what you're asking about is how to get to some of the datapoints I listsed (for instance, "share of tweets retweeted" , above).

Here, again, I would point you to the Twython and [Twitter API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), which you really should get to know if you plan on working a lot with this sort of data. But to point you in the right direction, here's how you could determine the percentage of original tweets from an author that get retweeted by others.

```
from twython import Twython
from __future__ import division  #assuming you're using Python 2.X

t = Twython(app_key='...',
        app_secret='...',
        oauth_token = '...',
        oauth_token_secret = '...')  #supply your credentials for each of these

tweets = t.getUserTimeline(screen_name='justinbieber', include_retweets=False) #see note below
retweeted_tweets = 0  

for tweet in tweets:
  if tweet['retweet_count']> 0: #...if at least one person has retweeted the tweet
    retweeted_tweets += 1

share_tweets_retweeted = retweeted_tweets/len(tweets) 
   #e.g., #number retweeted divided by total number of sampled tweets
```

What these steps do is pull in up to 200 tweets that have appeared in the user's timeline. The **include_retweets=False** part may seem confusing, but it's necessary. What that does is exclude tweets that other people have written that the author you're interested in (in this case Justin Bieber) retweeted, because what you want to know is how many people retweet your author when he or she writes original content.   We iterate over the user's timeline, and determine the number of their tweets that were retweeted by at least one person. We then divide that by the total number of sampled tweets, and that gives us the share that gets retweeted.

Note that this doesn't take into account pagination (e.g., navigating through multiple pages of a timeline -- you can only request 200 tweets from a timeline at a time, and up to 5000 total), which is something you'd probably want to implement.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the answer but using twython how to collect retweets .It is easy to get the followers count by Twython

Comment: @vishal1985, see my edits above, which give you a bit of guidance on how to go about using Twython to get data about retweets.   Given that your original question is not really about how to use Twython, but about how to measure influence on Twitter, I'd recommend opening a new question for any questions about Twython itself.  I believe my original post answers your original question -- and if you agree, would you mind choosing my answer? :)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your effort and great simple explanation.One more thing then if a person has got more retweets can we consider him/her as an inflential person or is some other metrics for that.Please can you clarify this also

Comment: Hey Benjamin ,one more thing the tweets which i am getting using this is only 15-20 .Is there any other means to increase up to 100-220

Comment: and how to get the retweeted text      Thanks

Comment: Re: more retweets and more influential -- that's entirely up to you :) ... it all depends on how you're thinking of influence and the features of your use case/business question/etc.  That being said, I would tend to think that if Person A gets retweeted more often than Person B, Person A is probably more influential (at least on Twitter) than Person B.   Re: getting more tweets/retweets -- for that, I'll just point you in the right direction -- which is this documentation on [traversing timelines] (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines).

Comment: re: tweet text -- for each tweet, that'll be under the 'text' field. so you could do something like:   for tweet in tweets: print tweet['text'] (this should be spread across two lines of course)...  Good luck!